# nav search bar in html/css or boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to replicate this UI structure.

Can anyone give some suggestions or point out some resources?

I specifically am having trouble connecting the search bar to the accompanying navbar.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some negative `margin-top` value to the search bar, it will shift a bit up and would overlap with the navbar, looking like the one you showed.